# Separation between the User machine and Server machine by another linux for monitoring

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, virtual-machine

I am planning to have three virtual machines with virtual box (m1, m2,m3).
I already installed on m1 = Windows XP Home Edition, and on m2 = LUbuntu 15.

**The big picture is this :**

m1 : a user

m2 : Firewall, or controller

m3 : Server

I want (m2) able to reach both (m1 and m3), but (m1) when it asks access to the server it will directed automatically to (m2) to capture the request and analyse it, then if okey, the request reaches the server (m3).

for the  (m3) I will install it later, but I don't know how to configure it this way.

Comment: Could you update to include precisely what your question is ?  Seems you need some advice on using `iptables` ?

Comment: What kind of requests do you want to filter? Is that about HTTP, HTTPS, or some other protocols?

Comment: @Gilles, I will be using modsecurity (it's an apache firewall module against web attacks).

Comment: The scenario that I need to implement is this: Example:
User ip : 192.167.1.1
MiddleOS : 192.167.1.2
Server: 192.167.1.3
When User "ping" to the Server (192.167.1.3), the request will be directed automatically to the MiddleOS (192.167.1.2) to do its job by analyzing the traffic if okey and the firewall said nothing the MiddleOS sends the request lets say HTTP request to the server (192.167.1.3).

So Only the MiddleOS have the ability to send and receive from both sides but the user can directly access the server.